# C++: Is it possible to make a multitype function parameter?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Is it possible to make a function `fun` that takes 1 paramater: array or a vector?
For example it will work if i do this:

I define the `fun(parameter)` function. `parameter` can either be a `std::vector<int>` type or a `int[]` type. I want it to sum up all the elements in a vector/array.

It works like a python function parameter(def = function decleration, stuff in () is the paramater list, whitout specific types, print == "printf("something")" in #include < cstdio > or in stdio.h):

```py
    def function(param1, param2): # param1 and param2  
        print(param1+param2) # can be any type that has a + operator
                            # which are float,int,str(string) and maybe some more
```

Is that possible, in c++?

Thank you, CppPythonDude.

Comment: The usual way is to pass a pair of iterators.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i am trying to make the parameter be a vector OR an array. It works if you pass a vector or an array.

Comment: _@CppPythonDude_ I believe @Swordfish has the right solution at hand.

Comment: @Swordfish can you show me some sample code, i never worked whit pairs?

Comment: Not only it is possible, but it can be implemented in several different ways: you can write several overloaded functions - one for each parameter type, or you can write a single template function, or you can actually implement python-style dynamic type system and write a function that accepts any kind of object..

Comment: Just a question: why am i getting dislikes? Idc for my rep ,but i want to know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I define the `fun(parameter)` function. parameter can either be a `std::vector<int>` type or a `int*` type. I want it to sum up all the elements in a vector/array.

How would you know the number of elements with only a pointer to `int`? The usual way is to pass a pair of iterators.

> can you show me some sample code, i never worked whit pairs?

You pass an iterator to the first element and an iterator past the last element of the range you want to iterate over. In interval terminology it is half-open `[first, last)`:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ForwardIterator>
long sum(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{
    long sum{};
    while (first != last)
        sum += *first++;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int foo[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << sum(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo)) << '\n';

    std::array<int, 3> bar{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << sum(bar.begin(), bar.end()) << '\n';

    std::vector<int> qux{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << sum(qux.begin(), qux.end()) << '\n';

    std::list<int> hugo{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << sum(hugo.begin(), hugo.end()) << '\n';
}
```

Heck, you could also have this function with only one parameter:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ForwardIterator>
long sum(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{
    long sum{};
    while (first != last)
        sum += *first++;
    return sum;
}

template<typename T>
long sum(T const &container)
{
    return sum(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
}

int main()
{
    int foo[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
    // please note that the array is passed by reference (no pointer):
    std::cout << sum(foo) << '\n';

    // sum(&foo[0]);  // wouldn't work because there is
    // no overload of std::begin() or std::end() for raw pointers

    std::array<int, 3> bar{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << sum(bar) << '\n';

    std::vector<int> qux{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << sum(qux) << '\n';

    std::list<int> hugo{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << sum(hugo) << '\n';
}
```

Of course don't reinvent the wheel: [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

The requirements for a type to be a forward iterator are that it supports the operations `iterator++` and `*iterator++`. A plain pointer can also be considered a forward iterator because these operations are valid with pointers. [LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator). In fact, a pointer is even more powerful and can be used as a random access iterator. [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)

But to address your original question: Besides overloading a funktion for different parameters or writinig a function template there is also [`std::variant<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) since C++17.

Comment: @CppPythonDude You should be keeping active and responsive with your posts. There may be a lot of things happening while you're asleep.

Comment: Haha... you said *"don't reinvent the wheel"*, Yes, we could have **better `sum` function**: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JBuV7ncTWjFUwywH

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-invent the wheel again: the C++ standard library has a function for exactly this purpose: [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). It takes two iterator arguments and returns the sum of the elements (you may also provide a third argument that defines your own version of the addition operator, allowing any type of accumulation operation):

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int foo[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo)) << '\n';

    std::array<int, 3> bar{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << std::accumulate(bar.begin(), bar.end()) << '\n';

    std::vector<int> qux{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << std::accumulate(qux.begin(), qux.end()) << '\n';

    std::list<int> hugo{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << std::accumulate(hugo.begin(), hugo.end()) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the function using the same name but different parameters.It's called function overloading, check it out.

Comment: so i define fun(vector) and fun(array)?

Comment: ... or use a function template

Comment: Yes and you implement both. You can have them do the same or different stuff but either way you must write them both.

Comment: @Clifford wat dat? i am dumb

Comment: @CppPythonDude : But now I've given you the search terms you could Google it ;-)